# Bulding a query of three tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have to three table I need to gather data from in a search process:

Commissions Table - Table1: `[affiliate_id]`
Affiliates Table  - Table2: `[id][user_id]`
Profiles Table    - Table3: `[ID][NickName]`

The search input I'll have is someone searched for a username. I need to return the data from table 1 where the affiliate_id matches the user_id of Table2, that is like the nickname that will be searched for.

I hope that makes sense :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
"select table1.* from table1 
inner join table2 on table2.user_id = table1.affiliate_id 
inner join table3 on table3.id = table2.user_id
where table3.nickname like '%".mysql_real_escape_string($searchtext)."%'"
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm joing on the correct fields here, but your query should look something like this.

Comment: Wow, thanks alot Oli.  That worked perfectly.  Can you explain what Inner Join do?  I want to sort of understand this query

Comment: I'm not too good at explaining, this wikipedia article has it all: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*, t3.nickname FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.id=t1.affiliate_id
JOIN Table3 t3 ON t2.user_id=t3.user_id
WHERE t2.user_id=?;
```